# populate_page_with method gives an error "Undefined method send_keys" when used with selenium web-driver

Tags: selenium, jruby, pageobjects, page-object-gem

I am using page object gem with selenium web-driver. I am trying to automate gmail sign in page. So to enter mail_id and password I am using populate_page_with method.

I am storing my login credentials in a variable "data"

**data = { :mail_id => 'abc@abc.com', :mail_password=> '12345' }**

And calling populate_page_with method like below

**populate_page_with data**

When I am trying run the script it gives an error *Undefined method **send_keys***.

But the implementation working fine when I am trying to automate yahoo mail sign in page.

**My page object class is**

```
class GmailSignInPage
  include PageObject

  button :gsubmit,                              :id => 'signIn'
  text_field :mail_id,                          :id => 'Email'
  text_field :mail_password,                    :id => 'Passwd'

  def log_in_to_gmail(data = {})
    self.mail_password_element.when_visible
    populate_page_with data
    self.gsubmit
  end
end
```

My step-definition is

```
Given /^I navigate to gmail page$/ do
  data = { :mail_id => 'abc@abc.com', :mail_password=> '12345' }
  on(GmailSignInPage).log_in_to_gmail data
end
```

In supports/env.rb, I have added PageFactory class also

```
World(PageObject::PageFactory)
```

If I modify my `log_in_to_gmail` method like below then also I am getting same exception

`undefined method 'send_keys' for #<NoMethodError: undefined method 'current' for Time:Class> (NoMethodError)`

```
  def log_in_to_gmail(data = {})
    self.mail_password = data['mail_id']
    self.mail_password = data['mail_password']
    self.gsubmit
  end
```

But if I use send_keys method its working fine except warning message

```
  def log_in_to_gmail(data = {})
    mail_id_element.send_keys data['mail_id']
    mail_password_element.send_keys data['mail_password']
    self.gsubmit
  end
```

And the warning message is

`*** DEPRECATION WARNING`

`*** You are calling a method named bridge at C:/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/page-object-0.9.2/lib/page-object/elements/element.rb:27:in 'wait_for_document_ready'.`

`*** This method does not exist in page-object so it is being passed to the driver.`

`*** This feature will be removed in the near future.`

`*** Please change your code to call the correct page-object method.`

`*** If you are using functionality that does not exist in page-object please request it be added.`

So I think, this is not the issue with `populate_page_with` method because even assignment operator `=` gives same exception. This may be due to page_object gem unable handle gmail sign-in page.

Comment: Can you please share the definition of your page object class? It would also help to give the full exception - ie the full message and stacktrace.

Comment: I have added my page object class. Could you please check. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have added GmailPage wrongly

Comment: Can you please give the full exception. The exception should say what object the `send_keys` method is undefined for (and therefore give more hints to what is wrong). I was able to get the page object working without any changes (using Ruby and Firefox).

Comment: This is the exception I am getting. undefined method `send_keys' for #<NoMethodError: undefined method `current' for Time:Class> (NoMethodError).

Comment: Hi Justin, I have added more inputs regarding this issue. Could you please check.

Comment: I installed JRuby and still cannot reproduce the issue. I would suggest creating a complete minimal working example - ie give all the code so that someone can copy the code and run it to see the problem. Though given that the error message talks about a `Time:Class`, I might guess the problem is else where?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets try this again.

I have created a test and copy pasted all of the sample code you have above (Using the populate_page_with() method). I did make one key change to my code compared to yours:

Yours

```
on(GmailSignInPage).log_in_to_gmail data
```

Mine

```
GmailSignInPage.new(@browser).log_in_to_gmail data
```

I don't know what gem the on() method from your code is from. I could guess, but I want to make this answer more fact based that my previous one. :)

Once I did this, I was able to successfully sign in to Google. So there is nothing unusual about the Google sign in page or any limitation I can come across in the page-object gem or anything wrong with your approach.

So the only things that are different between us is the one line of code I put above, our dev environments, other dependent gems each of us are using.

Try replacing the above line and see if that works.

If not, I would recommend seeing if you have a gem conflict of some sort. Reason I suspect this is due to the strange exception methods you are getting:

> undefined method 'send_keys' for # (NoMethodError)

The send_keys part I get, but 'current'? No 'current' method is being called and the Time class is no where to be seen in this example. That's one issue to look at isolating and seeing if you can clean up.

Comment: You raise a good point, but I do not believe that would cause an "Undefined method send_keys" error. The [`populate_page_with`](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/blob/master/lib/page-object/page_populator.rb#L32-L39) is ignoring keys that do not map to fields. So `{ :mail_id => 'abc@abc.com', :password => '12345' }` would have inputted the mail_id field, ignored the :password key and then moved on without an exception.

Comment: Even if I change to mail_password it's giving same error.

Comment: The `on` method is part of the Page-Object gem. It comes from the [`PageObject::PageFactory`](http://rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object/master/PageObject/PageFactory:on).